# Web Scrape, Python and BeautifulSoup, how to store output

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to use webscrape method to get some Temperature and Precipitation data for [www.wunderground.com](http://www.wunderground.com) (they have an API, but I must use web scrape method in my project)

My problem is that I can't figure out how to store my data after the scrape.

There is my code for example:

```
import urllib2  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2014/5/25/DailyHistory.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

#Mean Temperature Values
mean_temp_row = soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')[2]
for tds in mean_temp_row.findAll('td'):
    print tds.text
```

The output I'am getting is:

```
Mean Temperature

15 °C


16 °C
```

I would like to know how I can get something like: `station = {"Temp_Mean":[15 , 16]}`

Comment: please provide a sample of data you parse

Answer (score 0):

Is this output format always the same ?
If it is, so we can see the info name is on the first td of the row. Then, there is an empty td, then the min, then empty, empty, and at the end the max.

So you could do something like :

```
def celcius2float(celcius):
    return float(celcius.split('°')[0].strip())

cells = Mean_Temp_Row.findAll('td')
name = cells[0].text
min_temp = celcius2float(cells[2].text)
max_temp = celcius2float(cells[5].text)

# Then you can do all you want with this suff :
station = {name: [min_temp, max_temp]}
```

Answer (score 0):

After considering the answer from TurpIF , here is my code

```
def collect_data(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    Mean_temp = soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')[2].findAll('td')
    temp = Mean_temp[1].text.split()[0].encode('utf8')
    rows = soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')
    for num,row in enumerate(rows):
        if "Precipitation" in row.text:
            preci_line = num
    Preci = soup.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')[preci_line].findAll('td')  
    perci = Preci[1].text.split()[0].encode('utf8')
    return temp,perci
```

So,

```
url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2014/5/25/DailyHistory.html"
temp,perci = collect_data(url)
```